# Define an operator for long equations

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, functions, operators

I'm trying to workout a long expression with derivations, the thing is I can't seem to transfer this problem to code.

What I need is a operator $D = l^\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} $ where $l^\mu$ is a vector. Problem is I have long expression, for expample I need to write a equation
$$(D + \epsilon + \kappa + \gamma )(D -\omega + \kappa)\phi == 0,  $$
where all functions  $(\epsilon, \gamma, \kappa, \phi) = (\epsilon(x^i), \gamma(x^i), \kappa(x^i), \phi(x^i)) $.

For this reasons defining $D$ as

```
DD = Sum[l[[i]] D[#,x[[i]]],{i,1,4}]&
```

Is not usefull because I would have to expand eqaution for $\phi$ and then rewrite is in terms $D[\epsilon,\kappa,\gamma,\phi]...$. Note that I choose to wtite $D$ as $DD$ in code so it isn't confused with Mathematicas derivative funciton.

There are other expressions which I need to write out and other derivatives.
Is there any way to define $D$ so that I can just write the equation and get the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define

```
x = {a, b, c, d};
l = {1, 2, 3, 4};
DD = l . D[#, {x}]&
```

and then use [prefix notation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prefix.html) to approximate your expression:

```
(DD[#] + ε + κ + γ &) @ (DD[#] - ω + κ &) @ φ
```

Comment: Yes, but it becomes very difficult to write out the equations in terms of $DD[expr]$.
I would like if it were possible to define $DD$ in such way, where we can just write out the expression and $DD$ is automatically mapped to expressions.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand what you need. What do you mean by mapping automatically? Can you give an example of what you need?

Comment: Considering the equation give above I would like to write (having already defined $,,,,,ℎ$ as functions of $^$)
 `(DD + ee + gg + yy)(D-oo+kk)ph  ==0`.
Now I would like automatically get the expressions as

`DD[DD[ ph]] + DD[ ee ph] + DD[ gg ph] + DD[ kk ph] + ee kk ph + 
  gg kk ph - DD[ oo ph] - ee oo ph - gg oo ph + DD[ ph yy] + 
  kk ph yy - oo ph yy == 0` 

which is the written out form.

Or define $DD$ in such a way, that this is done automatically, which was my original question.

Comment: Automatically means not having to rewrite the expressions by hand.

Comment: ok maybe now I got it, please see update

Comment: Yeah, just what I needed.
Thank you